# Passport stamps art, can it be done?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

I've seen a photo in [Twitter](https://twitter.com/SHE5WN6ON/status/1125891667809177600?s=20) claiming that someone managed to make an art out of immigration stamps, as follows:

[image]

Is it really possible to ask immigration officers to stamp in a certain way to end up having a similar art?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93571/discussion-on-question-by-nean-der-thal-passport-stamps-art-can-it-be-done).

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This is not a photo of a real passport, it is a composite made for [an ad campaign for Land Rover](http://theinspirationroom.com/daily/2011/land-rover-defender-passports/).

Genuinely producing such an artwork seems quite implausible to me, since border officers will want to place entry stamps so that the date of entry is legible, since that's the whole point of the stamp. While it's common to ask them to stamp on a specific page to save space, a request to stamp on top of an existing stamp will almost certainly be refused.

Comment: I'd bet that even in the extremely improbable chance that a Passport Control Officer *does* stamp their stamp on top of another, if that's noticed by a subsequent Officer, they're likely to pull you aside and assume the passport itself, or your travels, have been faked/tampered with which is a big no no.

Comment: @BruceWayne It's not clear. What kind of idiot would fake passport stamps in a way that looked inherently stand-out suspicious?

Comment: I wonder if customs officers could be convinced to stamp some other piece of paper in something obviously not-a-passport, using that for the artwork instead of an actual passport....

Comment: @whatsisname Seems unlikely to me. Maybe at a very quiet border post.

Comment: You might be more likely to get a "fun" stamp on the incoming journey to your home country where you are a citizen. For example when I return to Australia with my kids (and australian passports dont get stamped), I have sometimes asked the customs officer for a "stamp" for my young kids (who think it is fun) and they often oblige.

Comment: @whatsisname As a stamp is an official signature I doubt any border officer would risk it for some "fun art" maybe with an in-official stamp, which is just for bookkeeping but not with the actual customs stamp

Comment: @DavidRicherby you're overestimating people.

Comment: @BruceWayne both me and my partner had passport control officers stamp on top of other stamps. Not super rare. Happened to me in Thailand, happened to my partner in Italy (to compare, her german stamp [which is also a schengen country, so they both have very similar stamps] is perfectly aligned).

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't expect it to be so serious. I have two entry stamps for France *exactly* on top of each other, rotated 180 degress, which makes the dates impossible to read. I've never had an issue with border control, and I even sent a scan of it for a french visa application (they needed only the first one... but oh well).

Comment: Even asking them to stamp a particular page won’t necessarily be very likely to succeed. They tend to want to maximise space usage to make sure you get as _few_ stamps as possible in my experience, and asking them to use an empty slot on a partly filled-up page will just result in a withering glare and a demonstrative placement on an empty page, smack in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an old passport, that has been properly invalidated by the authorites (they cut off a corner where I live, I suppose that's the common practice), then you could ask the border officer if he might be willing to help your art project out by placing a stamp in the old one.

They might still refuse, accept that and move on. Also, do the rest of the world a favor and don't ask this when there's people waiting behind you.